# Session error description: Couldn't set up DTLS-SRTP on RTP channel

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p

I am currently facing this error of not being able to set up remote SDP as there is an error in session description - `Couldn't set up DTLS-SRTP on RTP channel`

Also there occurs a two round of offer/answer round in peer to peer(which shouldn't) as `onnegotiationneeded` fires twice. This occurs during video conference setup in multi peer connectivity, otherwise the datachannel set up in the multiple peer connection(used to stream external video) works fine. The code below initiates the peer connection -

```
// Initiating peer connection with the host
function initiatePeerConnection(currentPeer, callback){
    peerConnection[currentPeer] = new RTCPeerConnection(serverConfig); // Initiation of RTC connection of peers other than host

    console.log(peerConnection[currentPeer]);
    console.log(currentPeer);


    peerConnection[currentPeer].onicecandidate = function(evt){
        console.log("ice candidate");
        console.log(peerID);
        signalServer.send(JSON.stringify({"candidate": evt.candidate, "peerID": peerID, "senderID": senderID, "sendTo": currentPeer}));
    };

    peerConnection[currentPeer].onnegotiationneeded = function(){
        console.log("negotiation initiated"+currentPeer.toString());
        peerConnection[currentPeer].createOffer()
        .then(function(offer){
            peerConnection[currentPeer].setLocalDescription(offer)
        })
        .then(function(){
            console.log("offer sent to "+currentPeer.toString());
            console.log(peerID);
            console.log(peerConnection[currentPeer].localDescription);
            signalServer.send(JSON.stringify({"sessionDescriptionProtocol": peerConnection[currentPeer].localDescription, "peerID": peerID, "senderID": senderID, "sendTo": currentPeer}));
            console.log("Done negotiation");
        })
        .catch(logError)
    };
    // console.log(localStream);
    // peerConnection[currentPeer].addStream(localStream);
    // peerConnection[currentPeer].ontrack = gotRemoteStream;
    navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, function(stream){
        localStream = stream;
        console.log(localStream);
        gotLocalStream(localStream, currentPeer);
    }, fallbackUserMedia);

    peerConnection[currentPeer].ontrack = function(e){
        console.log("on track");
        gotRemoteStream(e);
    };
    callback(currentPeer, setupChannel); // callback is createDataChannel. calling the callback with setupChannel
}
```

the code below answers to the offer/message received from server -

```
if(message.sessionDescriptionProtocol) {
        console.log(message.sessionDescriptionProtocol.type)
        if(message.sessionDescriptionProtocol.type == 'offer') {
            peerConnection[currentPeer].setRemoteDescription(message.sessionDescriptionProtocol)
            .then(function(){
                return peerConnection[currentPeer].createAnswer();
            })
            .then(function(answer){
                createLocalDescription(answer);
            })
            .catch(logError)
        }else{
            console.log(currentPeer);
            peerConnection[currentPeer].setRemoteDescription(message.sessionDescriptionProtocol)
            .catch(logError);
        }

    // });
} else if(message.candidate) {
    console.log("adding");
    peerConnection[currentPeer].addIceCandidate(message.candidate);
    console.log("added");
}

function createLocalDescription(answer){
    peerConnection[currentPeer].setLocalDescription(answer)
    .then(function(){
        console.log("answer sent to "+currentPeer.toString());
        console.log(peerID);
        console.log(peerConnection[currentPeer].localDescription);
        signalServer.send(JSON.stringify({"sessionDescriptionProtocol": peerConnection[currentPeer].localDescription, "peerID": peerID, "senderID": senderID, "sendTo": currentPeer}));
        console.log("Done");
    })

}
```

Here is the link to the [repository](https://github.com/P2PSP/Virtual-Room/) if needed

Thanks in advance :D